# Link Sails's authenticated user to websocket's user

Tags: angularjs, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I am currently trying to create an sails+angular web-app.
I already have a user-authentication system working (based on this tutorial : https://github.com/balderdashy/activity-overlord-2-preview). I am trying to integrate a very simple chat inside using websocket.

**My issue is to link websocket's "user" to the authenticated user.**

Because when an authenticated user writes a message, I want to send the message as data but not the id of the current user, i would like to get this id from the sail's controller.

This is my actual sails chatController :

```
module.exports = {

  addmsg:function (req,res) {

    var data_from_client = req.params.all();

    if(req.isSocket && req.method === 'GET'){
      // will be used later
    }
    else if(req.isSocket && req.method === 'POST'){
      var socketId = sails.sockets.getId(req);

     /* Chat.create(data_from_client)
        .exec(function(error,data_from_client){
          console.log(data_from_client);
          Chat.publishCreate({message : data_from_client.message , user:currentuser});
        }); */
    }
    else if(req.isSocket){
      console.log( 'User subscribed to ' + req.socket.id );
    }
  }
  }
```

and this is my angular's controller

```
io.socket.get('http://localhost:1337/chat/addmsg');
      $scope.sendMsg = function(){
        io.socket.post('http://localhost:1337/chat/addmsg',{message: $scope.chatMessage});
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
req.session.me
```

...was the solution.